# Remove jumping of colon symbol on a web page

Tags: css, fonts, typography

I have a web page with time on it `12:45`. User can click on that time to hide it (second click will show it again). Then the time is hidden it is shown as `−−:−−`.

I want to prevent jumping of elements when user clicks.

There is no horizontal movement, but there is vertical. When the time changes to minuses (and back) the colon moves.

Here is an animated gif that shows jumping colon:

[image: jumping colon on a web page]

Here is a jsfiddle with the code that shows the problem https://jsfiddle.net/a7z63nkp/5/

How can I change the code to make colon static?

Comment: just you want to make colon static ?(ie) colon should be static and 12 ,14 should blink(will be changing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are u expecting like this:

```js
var i = 0;
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
  if (i === 0) {
    // here is 'minus' ('−') chars, not the 'dash' ('-') chars
    $('.mins').text('−−');
    $('.secs').text('−−');
    i = 1;
  } else {
    i = 0;
      $('.mins').text('12');
      $('.secs').text('45');
      }
}, 300);
```

```css
.main{
  display:flex;
}
.mins, .secs {
  font-size: 10rem;
  width:200px;
  font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
  font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont;
}
.colon{
    font-size: 10rem;
    width:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
 <span class="mins">12</span>
<span class="colon">:</span>
<span class="secs">45</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works very well. I would prefer not to create several divs, but to use one. But if I will not find out how to do it I will use your solution.

Comment: I removed divs ,replaced all divs by span. even u don't want to use span?